# Javascript reduce - one argument takes on a wrong value

Tags: javascript, object, filter, reduce

I've been trying my hand at using reduce in javascript for the first time, based on this short article:
[Understand Javascript Array Reduce in 1 Minute](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/javascript-array-reduce)

I had two similar objects, one had a set of 20 keys, while the other had 30 keys, 20 of which the same as for the first object. Now, my purpose was to use reduce to create a new object, which would be a copy of the second object but only with those 20 keys (so that I could compare the first and second object).

I was using the following code:

```
const first = mapOrder(order, contactId);
const third = Object.keys(first).reduce((obj, key) => {
  obj[key] = second[key];
  return obj;
})
```

So the problem I encountered was with the obj parameter of reduce. I would get the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot create property 'name' on string 'id'`

It seems that my obj parameter was being initialized as as string with value 'name' ('id' was the first key of my first object).

So what I did, which ended up giving me the right results was as follows:

```
const first = mapOrder(order, contactId);
const third = Object.keys(first).reduce((obj, key) => {
  if(typeof obj == 'string'){
    obj = {}
  }
  obj[key] = second[key];
  return obj;
})
```

Could anyone explain to me why I encountered such a problem and how to fix it without making my code so ugly? Maybe I am missing something about how *reduce* actually works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this in your code

```
const first = mapOrder(order, contactId);
const third = Object.keys(first).reduce((obj, key) => {
  obj[key] = second[key];
  return obj;
}, {})
```

since the syntax is

> arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])

for more reference check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a initialValue (a new object) for the accumulator for [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

> **initialValue**
>
> [Optional] Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the `callback`. If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. Calling reduce on an empty array without an initial value is an error.

```
const third = Object.keys(first).reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = second[key];
    return obj;
}, {})
// ^^
```